# Bouncy Castle Default Modes AES 256

Tags: bouncycastle, aes

I need to know what is the default mode that Bouncy Castle AES 256 uses.

From what i know there are 
 six confidentiality modes (ECB, CBC, OFB, CFB, CTR, and XTS-AES), one authentication mode (CMAC), and two combined modes for confidentiality and authentication (CCM and GCM).

Please tell me which mode Bouncy Castle AES 256 uses by default

Comment: There is no such thing as a default mode. You specify the mode by the class you use.

Comment: Here is the code that decrypts the encrypted data successfully.                                                 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", new BouncyCastleProvider()); cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64 .decode(encrypted_pin_password.getBytes()));

Comment: Hi Guys, this has gotten really urgent. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the created Cipher object in a debugger. The Cipher.c member has an org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB object. So it looks you are getting ECB mode.